# Cross-correlation for univariate GARCH models

Tags: estimation, covariance-matrix, garch

I have a strange and maybe stupid question about cross-correlation.
Let's imagine having 2 times series, for example, `asset A` and `asset B`. Both time series have enough history.
Suppose, I've calibrated an ARFIMA-GARCH (or maybe just a GARCH) models for both and want to calculate cross-correlation between series based on these models I've calibrated. Is it possible to do and how?
So, more widely, if we have `N` calibrated univariate ARFIMA-GARCH / GARCH  models, can we calculate the covariance matrix based on these models?
Sorry if this question is so stupid.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can we calculate the covariance matrix **based on these models**?

No, we cannot, because these models tell nothing about the dependence *between* the series, only about the time dependence *within* each the series. There are multivariate conditional mean models such as VAR that deal with cross correlations (and multivariate GARCH models such as BEKK or DCC that deal with corresponding relationships for the second moments).

Comment: Thank you very  much!

Comment: @Dmitriy, you are welcome!